# Using a for loop inside a clocked process: "Cannot generate logic"

Tags: verilog

I would like to generate a number of statements inside a clocked process, seen below:

```
    parameter C_INPUT_LENGTH      = 32;
    parameter C_OUTPUT_NUM_BITS   = 5;

    reg [C_OUTPUT_NUM_BITS-1:0]        address;
    reg [C_INPUT_LENGTH-1:0]           vector_i;

    always@(posedge clk) begin        
       if(rst) begin
          address <= 0;
       end 
       else begin

         if (vector_i[0] == 1) begin
            address <= 0;
         end

         if (vector_i[1] == 1) begin
            address <= 1;
         end

         ...

         if (vector_i[C_INPUT_LENGTH-1] == 1) begin
            address <= C_INPUT_LENGTH-1;
         end

       end
    end // always@ (posedge clk)
```

I did so like this:

```
    integer                            forcount;
    always@(posedge clk) begin        
       if(rst) begin
          address <= 0;
       end 
       else begin

          for (forcount = 0;forcount <= C_INPUT_LENGTH-1 ;forcount = forcount + 1) begin
             if (vector_i[forcount] == 1) begin <--
                address <= forcount;
             end
          end 

       end
    end // always@ (posedge clk)
```

Xilinx vivado (2014.1) gives the following error, referring to the line indicated above:

```
[Synth 8-903] failed to generate logic
```

I've done this before using a similar method in the past and it has worked, what am I doing wrong? How do I generate these if statements?

Comment: Synthesis tools unroll loops. Depending on the value of `C_INPUT_LENGTH` and your clock cycle time constraint, the unrolled logic may not fit in one clock cycle. Have you tried increasing the clock cycle time or decreasing `C_INPUT_LENGTH`?

Comment: @Ari even if the for loop didn't fit into a single clock cycle that wouldn't prevent it from synthesizing.

Comment: Also, you may want to try separating the combinational and sequential logic blocks. I would put the for loop inside an always_comb block and assign its output to `address` in the `always` with `(@posedge clk)`. Looks like you want to find the first 1 bit in a single cycle, which is a combinational logic anyway.

Comment: See here: http://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/board/crawl_message?board.id=SYNTHBD&message.id=8970.  try: `if (vector_i[forcount] == 1'b1)` instead of `if (vector_i[forcount] == 1)`

Comment: @ari What combinatorial code are you referring to? everything is in an always block.

Comment: @StaceyAnne: Here I separated comb. and seq.: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/RL

Comment: @ari, I'm curious,  what's the advantage of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Xilinx, this is a known bug documented under CR 801365. The use of an integer as a loop counter causes this issue in some cases. It's due to be fixed in vivado 2014.3.

The solution is to replace the integer with a signal type reg of appropriate size.

Answer (score 0):

Is your input vector_i one-hot?  The code you wrote doesn't guarantee that address will only be written to one value.  Try this:

```
for (forcount = 0;forcount <= C_INPUT_LENGTH-1 ;forcount = forcount + 1) begin
  if (vector_i[forcount] == 1) begin
     address <= forcount;
     break;
  end
end
```

Adding the break statement will break out of the for loop the first time the condition is true.  Note that this will generate some carry-chain logic and you might get better results with a [case statement](http://www.nandland.com/verilog/examples/example-case-statement.html).

Comment: It's not one-hot, the goal is to give the higher addresses priority. I want the upper addresses to overwrite the lower. It's a leading one detector.

Comment: So then you need to either be doing `if` `else` or you definitely need to use the `break`.

Comment: I want the upper addresses to overwrite the lower. it's designed that way on purpose and works the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary work-around, you could consider using a generate statement.

For example:

```
genvar i;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) begin
    address <= 0;
  end else begin
     generate 
       for (i = 0; i < C_INPUT_LENGTH; i = i + 1) begin: foreach_input
         if (vector_i[i]) address <= i;
       end
     endgenerate
   end // if (rst)
 end  // always @(posedge clk)
```

edit: oh, never mind -- I missed the bit above where Xilinx's recommended workaround is to simply use a dimensioned variable rather than "integer" for the iterator.  That would be easier!

Comment: +1 because I haven't seen a generate used in that way.

Comment: @StaceyAnne, you done see `generate` used in this way because this syntax is illegal. For Verilog, a `generate` blocks can only be placed in a module. They cannot be placed inside `always` blocks. If you move the `always` inside the generate for-loop, you will have legal syntax but it will still be unsynthesizable because there are multiple drivers on `address`.